# URL rewrite : internal server error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a little problem on Apache's rewrite rules

Here's my rules

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule query/(.*) /php/query.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule page/(.*) /php/page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It works perfectly. But when I try to add the following rule to rewrite URL that not matches the two previous rules

```
RewriteRule .* /php/page.php?page=home
```

The server responds "Internal server error". Why ?

Comment: Look into your server’s error log! (Most likely you have created an endless redirect here, because `.*` of course matches `php/page.php` as well.)

Comment: The second rule match before .*

Comment: No, not for the (internal) request for `/php/page.php?page=home`

Comment: The rules are stored in .htaccess file. The documentation say in that case the rewrited request is passed again to the engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RewriteLog` to see what happends, but even with a `[L]` you can be sure a rewrited url is always re-checked on the set of rules (this is call internal redirect).

So add some `RewriteCond` before this final catch-all, or prevent it to be running on internal redirects, this way:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

You could also add the `[NS]` or `[nosubreq]` tag on your final catch-all, which does the same.

But preventing your rule on internal redirection also means it will never be applied after any previous rule, and one day you might want it. So be careful with next rules.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !

Finally, here's my solution :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule query/(.*) /php/query.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule page/(.*) /php/page.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ page/home [L,R]
RewriteRule ^$ page/home [NS,R]
```