# Unable to ignore mod_rewrite internal redirects with NS flag

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have defined a couple `mod_rewrite` rules in an `.htaccess` file, one to rewrite the URL path from `/rwtest/source.html` to `/rwtest/target.html`, and another to prohibit direct access to `/rwtest/target.html`. That is, all users wishing to see the content of `/rwtest/target.html` must enter `/rwtest/source.html` in their URL bar.

I was trying to use the `NS` flag in the forbid rule to prevent rewritten URLs from being denied as well, but it appears this flag does not distinguish between the first request and the internal redirect. It would seem that `NS` should do the job, but I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something.

Can someone please clarify this behavior? What exactly makes this internal redirect not an internal subrequest that the `NS` flag can ignore?

## Details:

Here's my full `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /rwtest

# Forbid rule. Prohibit direct access to target.html. Note the NS flag.
RewriteRule ^target.html$ - [F,NS]

# Rewrite rule. Rewrite source.html to target.html.
RewriteRule ^source.html$ target.html
```

I'm running Apache 2.4.9 on Windows 7 x64, but I've observed similar behavior on Apache 2.4.3 on Linux. Here's Log output for a request to `/rwtest/source.html`.

```
[rewrite:trace3] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/source.html -> source.html
[rewrite:trace3] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] applying pattern '^target.html$' to uri 'source.html'
[rewrite:trace3] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/source.html -> source.html
[rewrite:trace3] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] applying pattern '^source.html$' to uri 'source.html'
[rewrite:trace2] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] rewrite 'source.html' -> 'target.html'
[rewrite:trace3] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] add per-dir prefix: target.html -> C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/target.html
[rewrite:trace2] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] trying to replace prefix C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/ with /rwtest
[rewrite:trace5] [rid#20b6200/initial] strip matching prefix: C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/target.html -> target.html
[rewrite:trace4] [rid#20b6200/initial] add subst prefix: target.html -> /rwtest/target.html
[rewrite:trace1] [rid#20b6200/initial] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] internal redirect with /rwtest/target.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rewrite:trace3] [rid#20ba360/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/target.html -> target.html
[rewrite:trace3] [rid#20ba360/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] applying pattern '^target.html$' to uri 'target.html'
[rewrite:trace2] [rid#20ba360/initial/redir#1] [perdir C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/] forcing responsecode 403 for C:/Apache24/htdocs/rwtest/target.html
```

## Workarounds

I've posted a few workarounds [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24258932/1727828).

Comment: "Can someone please clarify this behavior?" - Yes, an internal rewrite is not a sub request. (You can also check the `IS_SUBREQ` server variable, which remains `"false"` for internal rewrites.) Other modules trigger sub requests, such as mod_dir and mod_include (SSI).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several workarounds for this, each with their pros and cons. As a disclaimer, I've only tested them in an `.htaccess` context.

---

## Workaround 1. Check for empty REDIRECT_STATUS

Add a `RewriteCond` checking to see if `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` is empty. If it is empty, then the current request is not an internal redirect.

#### Pros

- Most direct way to determine internal redirect.

#### Cons

- Lack of documentation. The page on [Custom Error Responses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) mentions this variable briefly:

  > `REDIRECT_` environment variables are created from the environment variables which existed prior to the redirect. They are renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix, i.e., `HTTP_USER_AGENT` becomes `REDIRECT_HTTP_USER_AGENT`. `REDIRECT_URL`, `REDIRECT_STATUS`, and `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` are guaranteed to be set, and the other headers will be set only if they existed prior to the error condition.

  I've tried every other `REDIRECT_` variable in `RewriteCond`, yet all of them except `REDIRECT_STATUS` were empty for internal redirects. Why `REDIRECT_STATUS` is the special one in `mod_rewrite` remains a mystery.

#### Example

```
# Forbid rule. Prohibit direct access to target.html.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^target.html$ - [F]

# Rewrite rule. Rewrite source.html to target.html.
RewriteRule ^source.html$ target.html
```

Credits for this approach go to [URL rewrite : internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809278/url-rewrite-internal-server-error).

---

## Workaround 2. Halt rewrite rule processing with END

Unlike the `L` flag, `END` halts rewrite rules even for internal redirects.

#### Pros

- Simple. Just an extra flag.

#### Cons

- Does not give you enough control over which rules to process and which to skip.

#### Example

```
# Forbid rule. Prohibit direct access to target.html.
RewriteRule ^target.html$ - [F]

# Rewrite rule. Rewrite source.html to target.html.
RewriteRule ^source.html$ target.html [END]
```

For more information see [END flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end).

---

## Workaround 3. Match against original URL in THE_REQUEST

> `%{THE_REQUEST}`
>
> The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1").

`THE_REQUEST` does not change with internal redirects, so you can match against it.

#### Pros

- Can be used to match against the original URL even in the second round of URL processing.

#### Cons

- Significantly more complicated than the other approaches. Forces the use of `RewriteCond` where just one `RewriteRule` would have been sufficient.
- Matches against the full URL which has not been unescaped (decoded), unlike most other variables.
- Inconvenient to use in multiple `RewriteRule`s. `RewriteCond`s can be copied above every `RewriteRule` or the value can be exported to an environment variable (see example). Both hacky alternatives.

#### Example

```
# Forbid rule. Prohibit direct access to target.html.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]+ ([^ ?]*)"  # extract path from request line
RewriteCond %1 ^/rwtest/target.html$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Rewrite rule. Rewrite source.html to target.html.
RewriteRule ^source.html$ target.html
```

Or, export the path to an environment variable and use it in multiple `RewriteRule`s.

```
# Extract the original URL and save it to ORIG_URL.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]+ ([^ ?]*)"  # extract path from request line
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ORIG_URL:%1]

# Forbid rule. Prohibit direct access to target.html.
RewriteCond %{ENV:ORIG_URL} ^/rwtest/target.html$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Rewrite rule. Rewrite source.html to target.html.
RewriteCond %{ENV:ORIG_URL} ^/rwtest/source.html$
RewriteRule ^ target.html
```

Comment: Thank you for such a full answer. Solved my problem!

Comment: Another "con" with the `END` flag... it's Apache 2.4+. Checking against `THE_REQUEST` has always been my "workaround" of choice.

Comment: "I've tried every other `REDIRECT_` variable in `RewriteCond`, yet all of them except `REDIRECT_STATUS` were empty for internal redirects." - Yes, I see the same behaviour. In the Apache 2.2 docs they are described as "_CGI-like_ environment variables", whilst they don't appear to be available to mod_rewrite, they are available in your CGI/server-side script (and useful for error documents - which appears to be the only place in the Apache docs where they are discussed).

Comment: I looooove you!